# How should I refer to a SharedArray hosted wholly on a remote machine in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

EDIT: Consider the example in the Julia docs:

```
$ ./julia -p 2

julia> r = remotecall(2, rand, 2, 2)
RemoteRef(2,1,5)

julia> fetch(r)
2x2 Float64 Array:
 0.60401   0.501111
 0.174572  0.157411

julia> s = @spawnat 2 1 .+ fetch(r)
RemoteRef(2,1,7)
```

On the last line does `fetch(r)` trigger data transfer (from the process to itself) or is it smarter than that? I.e. does process 2 use the fact that the reference is local to it and not initiate network transfer when `fetch` is called on `r`?  (EDIT 2: I think the answer is that fetching a variable from the same process doesn't trigger transfer.)

Second part of question: say I have a SharedArray `S` created on `1` whose memory is entirely on `2` (a process on a separate machine). The name `S` is defined on `1` but undefined on `2` despite the fact that the memory is there.

```
julia> topo  #my network topology separating processes on different machines
Dict{Any,Any} with 3 entries:
  36 => [25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
  48 => [37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48]
  24 => [1,22,23,24]

julia> sas = Dict()
Dict{Any,Any} with 0 entries

julia> for k in keys(topo)
       sas[k] = SharedArray(Int, (3,4), init = S -> S[localindexes(S)] = myid(), pids=topo[k])
       end

julia> @fetchfrom 36 sum(sas[36])
366

#the memory is definitely on a remote machine
julia> @fetchfrom 1 sum(sas[36]) 
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
```

But the dictionary `sas` of `SharedArrays` doesn't live on the remote machines, so must have been transferred over during the `@fetchfrom` statements.

```
julia> @everywhere sas
ERROR: On worker 22:
UndefVarError: sas not defined [...]
```

So I'm trying to get my head round whether there is any variable, say on `36`, which points at the memory that is available there, without transferring across the `sas` `Dict`?

Comment: Could you please write more precisely what is the goal of the task? What is to do, where do we compute, and where is the navigation center?

Comment: `remotecall_fetch(remotes[1],sum,S)`, will run command and fetch result all-in-one, but I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for. Because from your question I undrestand that you want to eliminate the fetching part. But It's natural and mandatory, when you run a command remotely, then the results do not locally available until you fetch them, nothing to do with `sharedarray`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work but some things are a bit more awkward now than you might wish. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13802 for discussion and some likely solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid it's me fishing around for other thoughts :) I think I'd find some kind of document explaining how the SharedArray functionality was designed really helpful. I guess the parallel section of the docs didn't pin down how the concepts work tightly enough for me.

Comment: Julia's source code is very readable; `base/sharedarray.jl` is the ultimate document.